# PHP - Oracle DB search not working

Tags: php, oracle, search

I have a page that allows users to search for people by their first name. So far I have tried several methods, including oci_bind_by_name but I do not get any results from query. Here is my current code:

```
if(isset($_GET['FirstName_Search'])){
    $stid_check = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT ID,UserName,Prefix,FirstName,LastName,Suffix,Title,Phone,Email,Department FROM WCM_People WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$FirstName%' ORDER BY LastName,FirstName');

    // bind values to the parameters in the parsed sql string
    //oci_bind_by_name($stid_check, ":FirstName", $FirstName);
    //oci_bind_by_name($stid_check, ":LastName", $LastName);
    $r = oci_execute($stid_check);
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid_check, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
    echo "<td>" . $item . "</td> \n";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

    // free the sql statement when finished
    oci_free_statement($stid_check);
}
```

And here are the warnings and errors that come with it:

```
   Warning: Division by zero     
   Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24338: statement handle not executed
```

It says the ORA-24338 error is coming from this line:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid_check, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
```

Comment: Try changing your query using double quotes: 
`($conn, "SELECT ID,... LIKE '%$FirstName%' ORDER BY LastName,FirstName")`

Comment: You're binding two variables you're not using...?

Comment: I commented that out, forget to comment it out when I posted here

Comment: Thanks Fred, that's all it was it looks like. Sometimes it's the little things.

Comment: You're welcome @mako It's your choice if you want me to make it an answer. Not in it for the points, just to close the question properly.

Comment: Or you can delete it too. @mako

Comment: Go ahead and answer it.

Comment: It has been done. @mako

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP's request to close the question.

Change your query using double quotes:

`($conn, "SELECT ID,... LIKE '%$FirstName%' ORDER BY LastName,FirstName")`

You are using single quotes for the search query while wrapping your query inside single quotes as well, which will not be rendered correctly and will in turn generate an error.